# d3js: Nodes don't collapse correctly in my tree diagram

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm creating a d3 Collapsible Intented Tree like [this one here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093025), but I'm having some issues with the way the nodes are collapsing.

If the top level gets clicked, there is no issue. The nodes collapse as they should. However if one level down is clicked, the node that was clicked takes the position of being the primary node, which is incorrect.

I was able to recreate the problem and set it up in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvznkveb/5/) for reference. I think it has something to do with the point wherd I use `JSON.stringify`, but I'm not sure. Here is that specific block of code.

```
d3.json("flare.json", function(flare) {
    flare.x0 = 0;
    flare.y0 = 0;

    console.log(flare);//Outputs flare.json

    //Takes the variable and exchanges the work "key" for "name" and "values" for "children"
    var source = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(flare).replace(/"key":/g, '"name":').replace(/"values":/g, '"children":'))

    console.log(source);//From what I can tell, this also outputs flare.json

    update(source);
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working.

On line 65 in the fiddle example from above, I call `update(source)`. The variable `source` needs to be assinged to another variable that can be called on line 72 in the `tree.nodes()` section.

I have [updated the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dvznkveb/11/) with a working example.

Thanks to @chazsolo for helping me to troubleshoot!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling `update` with a new source, specifically, the element that you clicked on

```
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
```

`d` is the element you've clicked on which is now referenced as `source` in your update function

```
function update(source) {
  // Compute the flattened node list. TODO use d3.layout.hierarchy.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(source);
  //...
}
```

To fix this, just use the original json object `flare` instead of a new source...

```
function update(source) {
  // Compute ...
  var nodes = tree.nodes(flare);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! How do I fix it? Do I need to call `update()` outside of the `click()`?

Comment: Isn't it using the original the way I have it in the fiddle? Because `source` is being created to get the JSON that is used with `key` being replaced by `name` and `values` being replaced by `children`.Then that gets passed into `update()`, which would be the original source, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: The only thing I did was change `var nodes = tree.nodes(source);` to `var nodes = tree.nodes(flare);` in your fiddle to get it working, which is how the example you provided works as well.  The rest of your code seems fine.

Comment: OK, that's exactly what I did, but I don't get anything back. [This is what my fiddle looks like](http://s27.postimg.org/jdwcqvfjn/fiddle.png)

Comment: What browser are you using?  I just tried the latest Chrome and nothing shows up there either.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 34.0 on Ubuntu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67043/discussion-between-chazsolo-and-bdd).